# reporting services asp .net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, reporting-services

How can we use reporting services in an MVC .net web application with Razor Engine. I'm starting with reporting services and any help would be appreciated

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I just want to display a report in an mvc .net application. Actually I have been looking for tutorials for that but I didn't find something helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx for instructions on how to use the report viewer control with asp.net MVC.